# How can I avoid adding href to an overlapping keyword in string?

Tags: php, regex, arabic

Using the following code:

```
$text = "أطلقت غوغل النسخة المخصصة للأجهزة الذكية العاملة بنظام أندرويد من الإصدار “25″ لمتصفحها الشهير كروم.ولم تحدث غوغل تطبيق كروم للأجهزة العاملة بأندرويد منذ شهر تشرين الثاني العام الماضي، وهو المتصفح الذي يستخدمه نسبة 2.02% من أصحاب الأجهزة الذكية حسب دراسة سابقة. ";
$tags = "غوغل, غوغل النسخة, كروم";
$tags = explode(",", $tags);
foreach($tags as $k=>$v) {
    $text = preg_replace("/\b{$v}\b/u","<a href=\"index.php?s=news&tag=$0\">$0</a>",$text, 1);
}
echo $text;
```

Will give the following result:

```
I <a href="index.php?s=news&tag=<a href="index.php?s=news&tag=love">love</a> <a href="index.php?s=news&tag=PHP">PHP</a>">love PHP</a>, but I am <a href="index.php?s=news&tag=facing">facing</a> a problem
```

Note that my text is in Arabic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way is to do all in one pass. The idea is to build a pattern with an alternation of tags. To make this way work, you must before sort the tags because the regex engine will stop at the first alternative that succeeds (otherwise 'love' will always match even if it is followed by 'php' and 'love php' will never be matched).

To limit the replacement to the first occurence of each word you can remove tag from the array once it has been found and you test if it is always present in the array inside the replacement callback function:

```
$text = 'I love PHP, I love  love but I am facing a problem';
$tagsCSV = 'love, love php, facing';

$tags = explode(', ', $tagsCSV);

rsort($tags);

$tags = array_map('preg_quote', $tags);

$pattern = '/\b(?:' . implode('|', $tags) . ')\b/iu';

$text = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function ($m) use (&$tags) {
    $mLC = mb_strtolower($m[0], 'UTF-8');
    if (false === $key = array_search($mLC, $tags))
        return $m[0];

    unset($tags[$key]);
    return '<a href="index.php?s=news&tag=' . rawurlencode($mLC)
         . '">' . $m[0] . '</a>';
}, $text);
```

Note: when you build an url you must encode special characters, this is the reason why I use `preg_replace_callback` instead of `preg_replace` to be able to use `rawurlencode`.

If you have to deal with an utf8 encoded string, you need to add the u modifier to the pattern and you need to replace `strtolower` with `mb_strtolower`)

**the `preg_split` way**

```
$tags = explode(', ', $tagsCSV);

rsort($tags);

$tags = array_map('preg_quote', $tags);

$pattern = '/\b(' . implode('|', $tags) . ')\b/iu';

$items = preg_split($pattern, $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

$itemsLength = count($items);
$i = 1;
while ($i<$itemsLength && count($tags)) {
    if (false !== $key = array_search(mb_strtolower($items[$i], 'UTF-8'), $tags)) {
        $items[$i] = '<a href="index.php?s=news&tag=' . rawurlencode($tags[$key])
                   . '">' . $items[$i] . '</a>';
        unset($tags[$key]);
    }
    $i+=2;
}

$result = implode('', $items);
```

Comment: I updated the line, but still not working $mLC = mb_strtolower($m[0],'UTF-8');

Comment: @AhmedGharamti: could you edit your question with arabic text (and arabic tags too)?

Comment: @AhmedGharamti: because of the particularity of arabic language (each character can be in several forms) I am not sure that using `(mb_)strtolower` is pertinent, perhaps there is a better way to be sure to find a keyword whatever the form of letter it uses.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling `preg_replace` multiple times, call it a single time with a regexp that matches any of the tags:

```
$tags = explode(",", tags);
$tags_re = '/\b(' . implode('|', $tags) . ')\b/u';
$text = preg_replace($tags_re, '<a href="index.php?s=news&tag=$0">$0</a>', $text, 1);
```

This turns the list of tags into the regexp `/\b(love|love php|facing)\b/u`. `x|y` in a regexp means to match either `x` or `y`.

Comment: @Barmar there is single quote to much in front of the explode

Comment: @AhmedGharamti I've added an explanation.

Comment: $text = preg_replace($tags_re, '<a href="index.php?s=news&tag=$0">$0</a>', $text, 1);

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: How can I avoid adding the href to same keyword if it was repeated in the same text.

Comment: @Barmar Adding the 1 to the end of preg_replace will only only add href to the first match and stop. try it

Comment: I see what you're saying. My answer will only replace the first of any tags in the input when you use that argument. If you need to replace each tag once, you need to go back to your loop, but you'll have to change the regular expression so that it uses a negative lookbehind so it doesn't match the word if it's already in an `href`.